# Installing Xdebug on Raspberry Pi

Tags: profiling, raspberry-pi, xdebug, raspbian

I want to improve the performance of my php scripts therefore I want to install Xdebug for profiling.

The problem is: I don't find how to install it on Raspbian!
I tried to install `xdebug, xdebug-beta, pecl, pear, ...` via `sudo apt-get install` -> not found

I also tried to install pecl manually:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

But the pecl/pear command is not availiable.

Do you know how I should do it?

Or do you even have better ideas for performance improvement/profiling techniques?

Answer (score 6):

The following steps should get it up and running for you. The below config is set up for netbeans and apache2. You may need to change the config at */etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini* if you want to use different settings. Make sure you don't skip changing the IP address mentioned in the second steps if you are debugging from a remote machine

---

First we need to install php5-dev and php-pear to make pecl available:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install php5-dev php-pear
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Then we just need to create a config file and enable it. The zend_extension parameter below will need to match what the pecl install output near the end. This is the only install location I have seen for Raspian. If you are not using Netbeans, you will also need to change the idekey property below. **If you are debugging from a different machine you must change the IP address next to xdebug.remote_host below**:

```
echo zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/xdebug.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.remote_enable=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.remote_mode=req | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.remote_port=9000 | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
echo xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug" | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
sudo php5enmod xdebug
```

Then just restart apache2 to use the new config:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

---

If you need to disable xdebug at a later date you can just run

```
sudo php5dismod xdebug
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

and re-enable it with

```
sudo php5enmod xdebug
sudo apache2ctl restart
```